# How can I use VLOOKUP in Excel with equality condition?

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, vlookup

I want to change data layout by filtering the left table from redundancies.
I tried typing the below formula.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(K8,$A$8:$E$82,5,FALSE)=$N$7,VLOOKUP(K8,$A$8:$E$82,4,FALSE),"na")
```

It just works with the date 3/1/2021, but not for the rest of the columns for the rest of dates.

[image]

Comment: Put a `$` in front of the `K`?

Comment: Also, please show us the formula in columns `O8`, `P8`, `Q8`, etc.

Comment: In O8 the formula is
=IF(VLOOKUP(K8,$A$8:$E$82,5,FALSE)=$O$7,VLOOKUP(K8,$A$8:$E$82,4,FALSE),"na")

Comment: In O8 and Q8 it was a try but didn't work

Comment: I tried the formula below but didn't work =VLOOKUP(K8&$N$7,$A$8:$E$82,4,FALSE)

Comment: Post data as text so that we can copy and past to our excel.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pPh4X3wxHjfXLEsaSVbG3qDc_JB_j9u2iRu8wsA9kQY/edit?usp=sharing